# Why isn't Lighttpd caching files?

Tags: cache, lighttpd

I've installed lighttpd 1.4.33 /not mod_cache patched/ on Ubuntu 14+. I've put .html file with embedded .unity3d on server (unity3d file is somewhere 50+ Mb.)

lighttpd.conf do contain `mod_expire`, `mod_setenv`, `mod_compress`. also, configuration do include following lines:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ ".unity3d" {
expire.url = ( "" => "access plus 7 days" )
setenv.add-response-header += ("Cache-Control" => "public, must-revalidate")
}
```

Every time I open this page, unity3d application starts to download again, not just opening from cache.

Here is what curl -I shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=604800
Expires: Tue, 17 Mar 2015 05:13:51 GMT 
Content-Type: application/vnd.unity 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
ETag: "2535721273"
Last-Modified: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 12:39:07 GMT 
Content-Length: 56645063
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 05:13:51 GMT 
Server: lighttpd/1.4.33
```

I did mention mime-type for unity3d files in proper config file.

Does anyone have experience or any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: downgraded to v1.4.26 + mod_cache to very same result

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean with "lighttpd is not caching files" - lighttpd never caches files, it just returns appropriate headers and may answer "304 Not Modified" given certain requests.

Comment: probably, you are right on title. I just wondering why unity file is not cached. I had an experience with pre-installed Apache and very same application. Tho, servers pings difference was significant (apache was closer, difference was x2), application acted like it was run from cache - the loading was in a snap. I heard a lot about lighttpd, but, unfortunately, can't make it run the way i want.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? a simple curl request will always return "200" - you need to give it some meta data from last time you downloaded the file to get a "304 Not Modified". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20978279/1478356

Comment: @Stefan, thank you! The thing was in size, actually. The files were too large.